# libreoffice pipe using python uno, inconsistant connection among computers, What makes difference?

Tags: pipe, desktop-application, libreoffice

I am currently checking my python project files on several computers (all Debian testing). I ran into inconsistent result and ran out of troubleshoot ideas.
This project uses python-uno pipe to communicate with libreoffice like following:

```py
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver",localContext)
cnxt =  resolver.resolve('uno:pipe,name=OOo_pipe;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext')
```

Problem is that this code works on one computer, but chokes on other two computers. Error message follows:

> **main**.NoConnectException: Connector : couldn't connect to pipe OOo_pipe(10)

Installed versions are libreoffice 7.0.4.2, python 3.9.2,
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop was checked, and same. When evoked, /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin runs in all computers. (also evoking scripts are same)

Installed packaged are not same among these computers.

What could cause this inconsistency?

Comment: I normally use sockets instead of pipes, for example in a shell script: `loffice "--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;" --writer &`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, socket works with me without inconsistency.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You should post an answer and then mark it as accepted. That way others may benefit from your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I answered myself, and accepted my answer. I also deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that an option string under Tools -> Options... -> LibreOffice > Advanced > Open Expert Configuration > org.openoffice.SetUp > Office > ooSetupConnectionURL was different.
With the working comp, it is "pipe,name=OOo_pipe;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" and is is empty with non working one.
[Documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.0/en-US/text/shared/optionen/expertconfig.html?System=UNIX&DbPAR=WRITER&HID=cui/ui/aboutconfigdialog/dialog-action_area1#bm_id6982839) looks somewhat slack.